# power off x4600 server via ilom

Tags: sun

Does anybody know how to power of a x4600 system via ilom. To reset the command is:
 reset /SYS

But i never found a power off command.

BR, Rene

Answer (score 3):

In the 820-0280-12 / Integrated Lights Out Manager (ILOM) Administration Guide For ILOM 1.1.1

it says:

```
8.1 Controlling Power to the Host Server 
■ To power on the host, type: 
start /SYS 
■ To power off the host, type: 
stop /SYS 
■ To reset the host, type: 
reset /SYS
```

Answer (score 1):

Try "stop /SYS".

"stop /CH" might also work (be carefull with this if you have a blade center!).

A "-f" (force) switch can also be added.

You can find more information about ILOM CLI in the [Sun documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19201-01/820-6412-12/overview_cli.html)

Comment: stop /CH is only for chassis systems (like Sun Blade 6000).  It won't work on x4600.  And, it will power off all blades in the chassis.